# JavaScript detect history back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history

I have a JavaScript function loads pages with very amazing. Here is my code:

```
function getpage(url, write)
{
    document.title = 'Loading Page... Please Wait...';
    waitingDialog.show('Loading Page... Please Wait...');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.get( url, function( response ) {
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");
            newDoc.write(response);
            newDoc.close();
            if(write!=true)
            {
                window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", url);
            }
            else
            {
                window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", '/');
            }
        });
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
    }, 10);
}
```

When user clicks product on my online shopping site it shows a loading modal.
And user's browser's url changes to product's link dynamicly. 
But when user wants to go back it is not working. 
I need to detect history back and history forward.
When user wants to go forward or back detect the back-url or forward url then load this url with my **getpage()** function...

**DEMO PAGE: https://shopnow.az/**

Comment: You need to write a [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) handler to restore the state of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`window.onpopstate = function (event) { 
// change content 
};`

This event will fire when user press back or forward button.

Comment: But how can I detect only user wants to go back?

Answer (score -1):

Try this function:

```
function getpage(url, write) 
{
    document.title = 'Loading Page... Please Wait...';
    waitingDialog.show('Loading Page... Please Wait...');

    var flag = false;

    window.res = null;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get'
    }).done(function(response) {
        flag = true;
        window.res = response;
    });

    myInterval = setInterval(function() {

        if(flag)
        {
            var newDoc = document.open("text/html", "replace");

            newDoc.write(window.res);
            newDoc.close();

            if (write != true) {
                window.history.pushState({"html": window.res.html, "pageTitle": window.res.pageTitle}, "", url);
            }
            else {
                window.history.pushState({"html": window.res.html, "pageTitle": window.res.pageTitle}, "", '/');
            }

            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast");

            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }

    },100);

}
```